# Can I use Plan Guides to optimize a slow performing Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

A synchronization program is syncing data between our SQL server and an online database. Every 5 minutes the program runs query's on all tables, al in the format:

```
select max(ID) from table
```

After that, the program retreives information from the online database, using the max(ID) to retreive only newer records.
The query runs fast on small tables, but some tables have millions of records.

The performance can be boosted by using a Where statement:

```
select max(ID) from table where date >= dateadd(dd,-30,getdate())
```

Unfortunately it's an old program, which cannot be changed anymore.
(no supplier and no source code)

I read something about Plan Guides, which should give performance boosts to query's.

Can I use a plan guide to alter these query's so they run much faster??

Answer (score 1):

I would try to stay clear of plan guides unless you have tried everything else to help SQL Server choose a better execution plan; reason, you are forcing SQL Server to choose maybe not the best execution plan and if your statistics are right, SQL Server does a heck of a job to provide you with a very good estimation plan.

Sorry if this is going to be long winded but SQL Server performance is based on statistics and if your statistics are off, your query will not perform optimally. This is where I would first start.

I would first run your query and generate an estimated execution plan and actual execution plan.  If you have never worked with execution plans, here are a few sites to start you off to understand operators and how to interpret some of the more common operators; [Rasanu Consulting (Joins)](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/19/understanding-hash-sort-and-exchange-spill-events/), [Microsoft (Joins)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426(v=sql.105).aspx), [Simple Talk (Common Operatiors)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/), [Microsoft (All Operators)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191158(v=sql.110).aspx).  The execution plans are generated from statistics SQL Server stores on indexes and non-indexed columns. I am assuming your query is stored in a procedure where the initial execution plan is stored.  Unfortunately, changes to the query in the stored proc can cause performance issues because of an outdated plan and the proc will need to be recompiled.

Based on the results of your execution plan, you may find a simple clustered index will help performance or find that fine tuning your where clause will result in better carnality estimates.  Here are a few sites that do a really good job explaining statistics; [Patrick Keisler](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/02/what-is-dbcc-showstatistics-telling-me.html), [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sql-server-query-optimization-no-unknown-unknowns), [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966419.aspx)

You may be wondering "what does this have to do with my question?" which would expect a simple yes or no answer but, effectively correcting query performance starts with an understanding statistics and execution plans.

Hope this helps!

Comment: At 200 histogram steps, there are data sets that will be unable to be adequately described by statistics alone. So saying that statistics is the be all, end all isn't a complete picture.

Comment: Statistics are the foundation to SQL Server estimation plans and a good place to start before using a plan guide.  For instance, he may use a single column predicate that reaches the max histogram steps and by creating a filtered statistic or multi column statistic will improve uniqueness hence better stats.

Comment: Thanks for your background story about SQL server, I know it's all about indexes, statistics, etc. But your answer doesn't help me.
The query is always run as "Select Max(ID) from Table"
It's very clear for me that adding "Where date => dateadd(dd,-30,getdate())" to it, is a great performance improvement. 
(Without the 'Where' clause it takes minuts. with the 'where' clause, it takes seconds)
I never worked with Plan guides. So in this case: A simple 'yes' or 'no' would help. And if 'yes', how do I do that?

Comment: No, could make things worse later down the road, check out this article from Bret Ozar http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/03/2-features-of-sql-server-you-should-avoid/.  Sorry, thought your query was one example of you trying to speed things up in your environment and was concerned to give you a one size fits all approach since there isn't one.  Having a predicate on your table, like the one you added, will naturally speed things up because statistically, you are working with a smaller set of data.  Hope this helps!